# Unknown column '$data' in 'field list' in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to insert data in my database and this error appears:

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$data' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `crud` (`$data`) VALUES ('')

Filename: C:/AppServ/www/parcial/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

This is my form:

```
 <?php echo form_open('home/save',['class'=>'form-horizontal']); ?>
  <fieldset>



      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Titulo</label>
    <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'id','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Titulo', 'value'=>set_value('')]); ?>

      <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'titulo','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Titulo', 'value'=>set_value('titulo')]); ?>


      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Resumen</label>
  <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'resumen','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Titulo', 'value'=>set_value('resumen')]); ?>

      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Ano</label>
    <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'ano','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Titulo', 'value'=>set_value('ano')]); ?>

          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Pais</label>
      <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'pais','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Titulo', 'value'=>set_value('pais')]); ?>
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Protagonista</label>
        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'progatonista','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Titulo', 'value'=>set_value('protagonista')]); ?>
  <br>


  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php echo form_submit(['value'=>'Submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary']); ?>
```

This is my function to save records:

```
  public function save() {

    $data = $this->input->post();
$this->load->model('Crudmodel');
if($this->Crudmodel->saveRecords($data)) {



}
}
```

this is my code to insert:

```
public function saveRecords($data) {

  return  $this->db->insert('crud','$data');


}
```

What can i do? please help me

Comment: $data is a variable so remove qoute first . And from where your data is coming in your controller .

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes, you need a array of key=>values that map to your table columns

```
public function saveRecords($data) {

  return  $this->db->insert('crud',$data);


}
```

Comment: It's quotes, not commas.

Comment: @Narf sory my bad

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove inverted comma from data field in it should be like below
return  $this->db->insert('crud',$data);
```

Comment: They're called single quotes, not inverted commas.

Comment: @Narf what is the difference between inverted comma and single quotes

Comment: "Single quote" is how virtually everybody in programming calls the `'` character and one could argue that it is a de-facto technical term. "Inverted comma" is slang and can refer to both a single or double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to execute this command:

```
return  $this->db->insert('crud',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
public function save() {

    $data = $this->input->post();
$this->load->model('Crudmodel');

$data = array (
            'database-fieldname' => $this->input->post('input-fieldname'),
            );

if($this->Crudmodel->saveRecords($data)) {



  }
}
```